# Unexpected end of JSON input on IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework, http-post

I want to do POST requests in IONIC but I'm facing the error 'Runtine Error: Unexpected end of JSON input' when I do a 'ionic serve --lab'. However, the data is well sent to the server because I can retrieve the data posted thanks to a GET request.

I use PostgreSQL server with PostgREST on my local machine.

Please find below the code:

```
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      let body = {
        id: lastIndex,
        title: 'POST N°' + lastIndex,
        description: 'Here is POST N° ' + lastIndex + ' ! :)'
      };

      this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/comments', JSON.stringify(body), {headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        alert("OK");
      });
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an error from the PostgreSQL side.
If you remove :

```
.map(res => res.json())
```

and you replace by :

```
.map(res => console.log("MAP"))
```

it works fine.

I don't know why but it works.

Comment: As of angular 5 (or even 4) the output from the http client is json, instead of Response. So no conversion needed.

Comment: So I have to change res.json on only res because the format is already JSON?

Comment: The format indeed is already json. Whether u should  change res is a different story. But yes you can.